# Javascript FileReader: Extracting text

Tags: javascript, scope, filereader

I'm having trouble preserving data extracted from a file read in by `FileReader`.

In the scope of the `onload` function the data seems to exist, but trying to store said data in a variable outside the scope does not seem to work.

MWE:
http://jsfiddle.net/eqaw0hbf/1/

(Upload any text file and you'll see what I mean)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My inclination is to say the onload function is asynchronous. In other words it triggers and only executes the "function(e){}" scope when the loading has ended (hence the name "onloadend"). In the mean time the rest of your program outside the scope of the "function(e){}" will continue to execute while it waits for the loading to end. It's not that the data isn't being stored in the text variable. It's simply that the line 14 "alert(text)" call is happening before "function(e){}" scope has a chance to set the 'text' variable to something other than empty.

As is your code would start and execute lines 2-3 and then jump to line 10 (and print alert(text) which is just "" because the function(e) never executed and so text was never set to anything). When the server or request that is "lr.onloadend" finally receives its data then your program will jump back to line 6 and execute the scope within lr.onloadend = function(e){} and set the text variable.

What you should do is put any data processing that relies on text INSIDE the callback of onload, inside this scope: `lr.onloadend = function(e){}`. Basically whenever you have an asynchronous function, anything that happens inside should be assumed to happen after all the code in any higher scope. Anything not inside a "callback" function will execute normally and in the order that you expect. Anything inside a callback function happens only when the callback gets triggered. So you can't make things outside a callback function rely on things that happen inside a callback function. There's no guarantee that information set inside an asynchronous callback that can 'trigger' whenever will be ready to use anywhere else.

This link does a decent job of explaining callbacks in Node.js/Javascript:

http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/javascript-callbacks/

Comment: I understand your explanation -- is there no way to wait for an asynchronous function to finish...? Is it possible to incorporate mutex variables in JS?

Comment: I don't think you can create mutexes. Javascript usually deals with everything on one thread. I will say (after reading the comments below on Brian's post) that no matter what you're going to be blocking code and it won't be very fun. You should check out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReaderSync You will have to use workers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker   Is there a reason you can't use the callback design pattern? Maybe if we knew the exact reason there is some solution that could be proposed.

Comment: Just for clarity. I wanted separate modules for handling different types of input data, and then another module to process said data through a neat interface. Everytime I think I'm falling back in love with JS, I get reminded of how pinickety it can be in its cleverness...

Answer (score 1):

That's because it is running more or less asynchronously.  The system is waiting for an event onloadend and then setting the text variable.

You can see this happening by putting in some sort of delay before your last alert.

```
function DoData(file) {                
    var lr = new FileReader();
    var text = "";

    lr.onloadend = function(e){
        text = e.target.result;
    };
    lr.readAsText(file);
    // this will display the correct result, after a delay of 1 second
    setTimeout(function() {alert(text)}, 1000);
    // this will display a blank string, 
    // because the text hasn't been loaded yet
    alert(text);
}
```

Normally, what you will do is add the processing function for the text variable inside the onloadend event.  That's the only time that you know, for a fact, that the text variable has been initialized correctly.

```
    lr.onloadend = function(e){
        text = e.target.result;
        functionToProcessText(text);
    };
```

Comment: the `setTimeout` function seems to be what I am looking for (I could incorporate all my code within the `onloadend` event, but it would be messy) -- it just seems a bit arbitrary to wait 1 second. Is there no `waitFinished()` function I can use?

Comment: 1 second was arbitrary.  The onloadend is the waitFinished function.  Once it has been invoked, you know that text is initialized.  Conceptually, you could trigger another event once onloadend has been invoked.  Alternatively, you could write your own waitFinished function that just does a setTimeout until text (or some arbitrary boolean processing flag) is not null or blank.

Comment: Is there really no cleaner way - No mutex support in JS? I don't want to have to block code execution manually using `setTimeout`

Comment: No, because JavaScript is single threaded.  In this case, JavaScript is just creating an event that the JavaScript engine will watch for, when it has time.